# CakePHP login redirect bug

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in my login method to redirect the user to their previous page and show them a message saying welcome back. I have disabled the autoRedirect to give me control so I can show a flash message and perform other actions on login.

```
    if(!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user())
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome back! <strong>' . $this->User->field('firstname') . '</strong>', 'flash');

        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect($this->referer()));
    }
```

This works fine when using login forms that are in the header, but when logging in from the actual stand-alone login page it redirects the user BACK to the login page and shows an error saying their username and passwords were incorrect and also the welcome back message. The users IS logged in though and can access the relevant pages BUT I don't want them redirecting back to the login page. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the referrer is the login page, and if so, redirect them to the home page.

**Edited to add a code example:**

```
if($this->referer()=='/users/login'){
    $this->redirect('/');
}else{
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect($this->referer()));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if they are from the login method rather than the URL as the url is changed via routing and this is running on localhost and therefore isn't the root so `/` wouldn't work!

Comment: What you are trying to do is to deal with the situation where they come from the login page - you don't want to send them back to the login page.  You need to check that the referrer isn't the login page.  Where you redirect them to after is up to you.  I used '/' as an example.  The else clause handles sending them back to wherever they logged in from if it wasn't the login page.

Comment: But how do I check if the referrer is the login page using the login method and NOT explicitly writing the URL as it could and will change depending on the setup.

Comment: Don't know that you can.  But, there should be a finite # of things to check for.  So, you could use an OR in the if statement to check for all of them.

Comment: Yeah seems you can. See my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user())
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome back! <strong>' . $this->User->field('firstname') . '</strong>', 'flash');

            //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect($this->referer()));

            if($this->referer(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')))
            {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect($this->referer()));
            }
        }
```